# How to avoid LazyLoad effect on specific class?

Tags: image, conflict, lazy-loading

Currently using following code found on web:

(using jq instead of $ sign)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.lazyload.mini.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
jq(function() {
    jq("img").lazyload({
         placeholder : "template/eis_d25_022/common/grey.gif",
         effect      : "fadeIn"
    });
});</script>
```

The above code just auto "Lazyload" everything in my forum without changing image class or image src etc. However some image with specific class doesn't load sometimes and sometimes it works:

```
<img src="straightlogo/what.png" class="vm" alt=" " original="straightlogo/what.png">
```

How to avoid Lazyload effect on vm class's image?? or how to make this vm class works??

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude elements with [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) selector.

```
jq("img").not(".vm").lazyload({ ... });
```

However it would be easier if you just specify class of images which you want to be lazyloaded. For example you can use class `lazy`. Also note that with current version of the plugin you define the placeholder in `src` attribute and real image in `data-original` attribute. For example:

```
<img class="lazy" data-original=“img/example.jpg” src=“img/grey.gif” width=“640” height=“480”>
```

Then you could do something like:

```
jq("img.lazy").lazyload({ ... });
```